# How to use javascript validating two text areas

Tags: javascript, validation

The below works, how would i go about including a 2nd "txtArea2"? I've tried joining a `& (document.getElementById("txtArea2").value == '')` but doesnt work. I'm new to js syntax if someone could help.

```
if(document.getElementById("txtArea1").value == '')
            {
                alert("debug");
                document.getElementById("txtArea1").style.display ="none";
                return false;
            };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly but you probably want to compare them with **||** (*OR*) operator, so if `txtArea1` **or** `txtArea2` is empty then the validation shall not pass. That means both textareas will be required fields.

```
if (document.getElementById("txtArea1").value == '' || document.getElementById("txtArea2").value == '')
{
    alert("debug");
    document.getElementById("txtArea1").style.display ="none";
    return false;
};
```

Comment: Thanks, the "or" is what I needed. Now if i could only know to make the || symbol haha

Comment: It should be somewhere above the `Enter` key on the keyboard. Press it with the `shift` key. Of course it's a single `|` character. You have to press it twice.

Answer (score 1):

Double `&&` specifies the AND condition.

```
if (document.getElementById("txtArea1").value == '' && document.getElementById("txtArea2").value == '')
```

Comment: oh ok, thanks. However this seems to validate only txtArea1 and disregards txtArea2.

Comment: If `txtArea1` fails that condition, then it doesn't care about `txtArea2`, it's an AND, so if one fails, the entire block is jumped./

Answer (score 0):

If you want to treat both separately, you'll have to use two separate if statements as well. (I outsourced the textareas into variables for readability)

```
var txtarea1 = document.getElementById("txtArea1");
var txtarea2 = document.getElementById("txtArea2");
if(txtarea1.value == '')
{
    alert("debug");
    txtarea1.style.display = "none";
    return false;
};
if(txtarea2.value == '')
{
    alert("debug");
    txtarea2.style.display = "none";
    return false;
};
```

If you want to do one thing if *either of them* (1 *or* 2) is empty, try this:

```
if(txtarea1.value == '' || txtarea2.value == '')
{
    alert("debug");
    txtarea1.style.display ="none";
    txtarea2.style.display ="none";
    return false;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var t1 = document.getElementById("txtArea1").value;
var t2 = document.getElementById("txtArea2").value;
if( t1 == '' || t2 == '')
{
   alert("debug");
   document.getElementById("txtArea1").style.display ="none";
   return false;
};
```